# Google Cloud Platform - Can't connect to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, cloud, google-cloud-platform

Just installed mongodb using click-to-deploy in google cloud platform. I have another project, for which I created the mongodb database, where my web application runs. 
Do I have to open some port or configure something?

Comment: I answered to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289948/mongosocketreadexception-prematurely-reached-end-of-stream-while-connecting-mo/76868718#76868718

Answer (score 15):

As the other answers in this thread suggest, `mongod` daemon is listening on TCP port `27017`. Therefore, you will need to [add a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#addingafirewall) on Compute Engine firewall for this port and protocol. This can be done using [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/add?) or using `gcloud` command tool:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-mongodb --allow tcp:27017
```

It is recommended to use target tag with the firewall rule and use this target tag to specify what VM instances the firewall rule should be applied to.

Answer (score 12):

Adding the port in the firewall is not enough. By default the host bind to 127.0.0.1 which needs to be changed to 0.0.0.0 
Make changes in the file sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf inside the instance 
Look for the term bindIp
change it to 0.0.0.0 and restart mongodb
You will be able to connect to the mongo db now

Comment: This is correct. The accepted answer should be "merged" with this one. In my Windows Google Compute Engine, I needed to open the same port in Windows Firewall too.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Http or Https checkbox to activate the external ip address so u can use it to access the database

Answer (score 0):

On the Mongodb project you should open firewall for port 27017.

MongoDB used ports are listed at:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/

Regards,
Paolo

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29141330/633107) explains how to set the firewall rule for port `27017`.

Another issue that could cause this is running your mongodb in a separate network and having your other instances on the default network (or vice versa).

I ran into this and after getting both instances on the same network, it was able to connect to the mongo instance by name.

Here's an example of how to set the network for a managed VM in your `app.yaml`:

```
network:
  instance_tag: https-server
  name: my-node-network
```