# Mongodb on Google Cloud -- Confirm content via show dbs?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've installed a MongoDB on Google Cloud Compute Engine via a [Bitnami script](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/config/bitnami-launchpad/mongodb).  I can see the vm instance in the Google Cloud dashboard.  I can connect to the database using my deployed node.js app.  My app works just fine.

What I can't figure out is how to independently verify the content in the Mongo database.

On the Compute Cloud dashboard for the Mongo DB VM, there is a SSH pulldown button at the top of the screen. Clicking this button opens up a browser frame.  The frame connects to the VM instance via https, and confirms login info. I've seen [this related stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776013/google-cloud-platform-cant-connect-to-mongodb), and I've met all of these suggestions. Settings confirmed at the Google Cloud VM instance interface. When I type `mongo` I can see the mongo shell.  When I try `show dbs` I get back unexpected results:

```
show dbs
2017-02-19T05:51:45.161+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listDatabases failed:{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
        "code" : 13,
        "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
} :
```

How can I do a simple `show dbs` and then `show collections` and finally `db.foo.find()` to confirm data content?

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. So it turns out I missed something.  When I created the instance the system sent me an confirmation email.  In the email were a couple of key links.

There are two very different methods to "connect" to the database.

The first is to open the mongo shell interface via an admin / login.

```
$ mongo admin --username root -p
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
Enter password: (password entered here)
connecting to: mongodb:///opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.2
```

This worked quite well, without having to transfer SSH keys at all. [Reference link here](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/mongodb/#how-to-connect-to-the-mongodb-database).  At this point I could

```
> show dbs
admin  0.000GB
local  0.000GB
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show collections
books
system.users
system.version
> db.books.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58a900452c972b0010def8a7"), "title" : "Mr. Tickle", "author" : "Roger Hargreaves", "publishedDate" : "1971", "description" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58a900612c972b0010def8a8"), "title" : "Mr. Sneeze", "author" : "Roger Hargreaves", "publishedDate" : "1982", "description" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58a93a192c972b0010def8a9"), "title" : "Mr. Happy", "author" : "Roger Hargreaves", "publishedDate" : "1971", "description" : "" }
>
```

The second method is to register SSH keys, via [these instructions over at Bitnami.com](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#using-the-google-cloud-launcher)

In this method, you have to first add your public SSH key via the Google Cloud interface to the instance.