# How to find mongodb connection string in Google cloud Compute Engine VM Instance (Bitnami)

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I have used mLab previously with below connection string. Now I am hosting my app in Google App Engine with my mongodb instance on Google Compute Engine using Bitnami. When I create a instance, I couldn't find the connection string.

mLab connection string: `mongodb://username:password@ds129010.mlab.com:29010/testdn`

But know the username and password. what could be the connection string

what could be the connection string for Bitnami GCP Compute Engine VM instance.

username: root, password: test

Answer (score 4):

The External IP of the instance is the host for the mongodb to connect.
The connection string would be

```
mongodb://username:password@<IP-of-the-instance>:27017/testcdn
```

NOTE:- Don't forget to open port 27017 from the VPC networks to access from outside the Compute Engine Instance like from your personal laptop

PFA the image depicting where to find the IP
[image: How to get External IP of an instance]

Comment: How to open port 27017 from the VPC networks to access from outside the Compute Engine Instance

Comment: I have replace host with External Ip, username with 'root' and password with 'temperory password generate'... still i get { MongoError: Authentication failed.

Comment: The default mongodb installation is without password, so you could connect to it without username or password, so the connection string would be mongodb://<IP-of-the-instance>:27017/testcdn

Comment: To open the port for mongodb, check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776013/google-cloud-platform-cant-connect-to-mongodb