# MongoDB timeout error in Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, minikube

I'm trying to deploy my app in Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine; it consists of backend (in Node.JS) and a DB (MongoDB).

When I'm testing it on my local VM within Minikube it works as expected - I can connect from the API to the DB.

However, when deploy it on GCP my API can't connect, and after checking the API's pod logs, I see the `MongoDB :: connection error: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms` error.

I don't know if it matters, but those two microservices are in the same node.

Is there any difference to be aware of between the local Minikube setup and the GCP setup?

Comment: Is like the port 27017 is closed...

Comment: Well, it might be, but it is not closed on my minikube then. How can I check is it closed or not?

Comment: What SO are you using?.

Comment: SO? Btw I established firewall rule to allow 27017

Comment: Then ....If you make telnet IP_your_App 27017....works?

Comment: Nodejs app and db are different pod ?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar telnet hangs: `Trying IP_your_App...`

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu yes, they are

Answer (score 2):

After all this helped me:
[Google Cloud Platform - Can't connect to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776013/google-cloud-platform-cant-connect-to-mongodb)

First answer shows how to add firewall rule but second is even more important to change IP address inside the mongodb config. May it be done easier?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the pods are running and there is no error in logs of the pod.
You might have a network policy which blocks pod to pod communication.Check if the cluster network policy enforcement is enabled and try disabling cluster network policy enforcement using cloud cli

gcloud container clusters update [CLUSTER_NAME] --no-enable-network-policy

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy